# How can I make my blog more popular?

Tags: blog, websites

I write an action movie review blog where a review is published every Monday. How do I publicize my blog to bring more readers my way?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Please note that we don't do feedback or critiques here: judging from the tags you chose, I'm guessing that was what you were looking for. I think this question can be answered without critiquing your blog's reviews, however.

Comment: No, I meant how to promote it

Comment: There are already [several hundred million answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+promote+blog) to that question. I don't think repeating them here will add anything new. I just want to point out the most important information: The market for film review blogs is absolutely oversaturated. It will be near impossible for you to attract any readers at all and your blog has to be outstanding to achieve that. Apparently more than 90% of content on the web get zero traffic. It might be a better strategy to begin as a guest writer for other blogs and create your own once you have made a name